# meaning of phrase "twenty-two-cent stamp" in sentence

Tags: expressions, sentence-meaning

In the sentence below from Liar's Poker, does the reference of twenty-two-cent stamp mean that many investors were now able to make a bid for a company?

> “There was this huge opportunity,” says Perella, “and it was lying under the dirt. You had a steady supply of companies whose assets were undervalued. But there was a paucity of buyers. People who wanted to buy these companies couldn’t monetize their desire. Someone—Milken—came along and kicked away the dirt. Now anyone with a twenty-two-cent stamp can make a bid for a company.”

**Research I've done:** 
I checked urban dictionary and tried to search on google how common 22 cent stamps were in the 80s.  However, the search didn't come up with anything useful.

Comment: I think the matter of 22 cent stamps was merely a way to say that mailing a bid might produce results. I suppose that 1st class postage was 22 cents at the time

Comment: February 17, 1985, 1st class postage went to 22 cents

Comment: You didn't research very much: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_United_States_postage_rates

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: @Hot Licks - you shouldn’t point out that I haven’t done research.  I’ve done research to the point that I wanted.  My curiousity to learn made me post this question.  Posts like yours, make people second guess themselves about asking questions.

Comment: @rds80 - That's not how it works here.  You should avail yourself of the resources at hand, by, eg, Googling for relevant Wikipedia articles.  Only if you do not understand after doing a reasonable amount of research should you ask a question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From February 17, 1985 to April 3, 1988, the cost of first-class domestic postage was...22¢.

Milken had made investing so easy, all you had to do was mail a letter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Whether 22¢ stamps were actually common is irrelevant. The meaning is that minimal investment was required to bid on a company.

Comment: I understand the meaning of the sentence.  But what is the relevance of twenty-two-cent stamp?

Comment: The implication was that all they had to do was send a letter